# Pebble Custom Phone Call Notification

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

Is it possible to override the default incoming call screen with a custom screen on the pebble watch?

Im guessing I could capture the interruption as described here - http://developer.getpebble.com/guides/pebble-apps/app-events/app-interruptions

Is this sort of customisation possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screen that shows an incoming call is a modal window shown by the system and cannot be overridden from a Pebble app running on Pebble.

There are however two things you can do on the phone:

1. From a mobile app on the phone, you can push a notification that will appear on top of the "phone" system UI.
2. *(Android only)* You can suggest to the user that (s)he disables the "Call Notification" in the Pebble app and then you will have control of the screen during calls (as suggested by [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354577/chris) in the comments. thanks)

Comment: But it is possible for users to disable phone notifications within the Pebble app and let another app send its own notification. This is how, for example, [Pebble Dialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.matejdro.pebbledialer) works.